# Mock exception flow in jackson object mapper

Tags: java, jackson, mockito

This is the method

```
public String getProductCategoryJSON(NestedProductCategoryMap nestedProductCategoryMap) {
try {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(nestedProductCategoryMap.getRoot());
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("error-code:{} error: JSON conversion failed ", JSON_CONVERSION.getErrorCode(), e);
    throw new ValidationException(ExceptionEnum.JSON_CONVERSION,e);
}
```

}

This is the test I tried but doesn't seem to work

```
    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void test_getProductCategoryJSON_Should_ReturnException() throws Exception {

    NestedProductCategoryMap nestedProductCategoryMap = new NestedProductCategoryMap();
    nestedProductCategoryMap.makeCat(1,"(");
    nestedProductCategoryMap.makeCat(2,"s2");
    String json="{";

    ObjectMapper objectMapperMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(objectMapperMock.writeValueAsString(any(NestedProductCategoryMap.class))).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("test"){});



    Assert.assertNotEquals(json,jsonUtil.getProductCategoryJSON(nestedProductCategoryMap));
}
```

> is there a proper way to do this internal mocking of jackson object mapper

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the block that asserts for the Exception:

Rewrite this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapperMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
Mockito.when(objectMapperMock.writeValueAsString(any(NestedProductCategoryMap.class))).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("test"){});
```

To this:

```
Exception exception = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
    ObjectMapper objectMapperMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(objectMapperMock.writeValueAsString(any(NestedProductCategoryMap.class)));
});
```